# Tengo problemas con el resize de de algunas pantallas?

Tags: javascript

buenos días.
Necesito vuestra ayuda para un problema que tengo con el resize de algunas pantallas.

Estoy contrayendo una web que al abrirla en algunos dispositivos que tienen el resize de la pantalla por defecto a 150% algunos elementos se rompen ya sean de css o JavaScript en algunos casos.

Em principio creo que lo suyo seria capturar el risize de la pantalla y si este esta a 150% reducir ese mismo porcentaje.

alguien sabría como se puede hacer ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: puedes trabajarlo con bootstrap, tiene varias clases en funcióon del tamaño de la pantalla con el que estes trabajando https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_grid_basic.php 
 https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_utilities.php

Comment: Mas que el tamaño necesito saber el resize de la pantalla (si tiene zoom). esta la funcion onresize() pero la función se utiliza para especificar qué sucederá si se cambia el tamaño de una ventana y yo quiero saber que resize tiene cada una de ellas. Por defecto suele estar al 100% pero hay dispositivos que no es así y querría capturar ese dato para después redimensionar si se puede su pantalla al 100%.

Comment: Aun así, bootstrap te sirve porque trata por igual el zoom y el tamaño de pantalla, ya que trata las dos funcionalidades por igual, lo que bootstrap mide es la cantidad de pixeles que estas mostrando por pantalla.